# How to set the height of the PageTabView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I want to show some images in pageTabView.But the image size image is compressed.
How do I control the size. My image is requested from the server.

```
struct TextView: View { 
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                BannerView()// <- how to set size?
                Text("aaaa")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BannerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                VStack{
                    Image(systemName: "pencil")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .tag(index)
                }.background(Color.blue)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.frame(height: yourDesiredHeight)`. However this will keep your image scaled as if you're using `.scaleToFit()` which will try to fit all of the image in the frame.

Try using `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)` to fill the whole frame.